# Выборка элементов из БД и смена значений

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как мне реализовать следующее.
По крону будет запускаться скрипт, который из определенной таблицы БД (dates, status) должен вытаскивать все значения, дата которых старше месяца от текущей даты. Дата в поле dates хранится в unixtime и ставит этим записям в поле статус значение inactive.

То есть, я так понимаю, нужно получить текущую дату в unixtime, потом получить дату на месяц раньше (-2678400), и если значение в dates меньше или равно получившемуся, то ставить статус inactive. Помогите с кодом в плане sql запроса, завис.

Comment: http://tsya.ru

Comment: Про ться в курсе, торопился...
P.S. Являюсь победителем областной олимпиады по русскому языку.. правда в далеком прошлом))) Сам себя ругаю, но сейчас печатаю быстрее, чем думаю)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> помогите с кодом в плане sql запроса завис.

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET status = 'inactive' WHERE dates <= :deadline
```

где `:deadline` заменяется на полученную временную метку.

Можно снизить количество обновляемых записей (понятия не имею, как это скажется на производительности):

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET status = 'inactive' WHERE dates <= :deadline AND status != 'inactive'
```

Comment: А deadline как раз и получается путем отнимания от текущей даты количество секунд в месяце? Вместо deadline переменную ставить?

Comment: @Batyabest, да